# How to use Gitorious with QtCreator?

Tags: git, qt, qt-creator, kde-plasma

I am learning the basics of version control and KDE development, using QtCreator.

I am not famililar with gitorius and how to manage the SSH keys and push the files I have on my system to the repo.

Can anyone explain it to me ?

How to set up my own repo using QtCreator and push it to gitorious.

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-version-control.html

Comment: Your question is too broad. Read the relevant documentation, search the web and than come with specific points you still struggle with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the **[Git tutorial](http://excess.org/article/2008/07/ogre-git-tutorial/)** by [Bart Trojanowski](http://www.jukie.net/~bart/) ([PDF version](http://edgyu.excess.org/git-tutorial/2008-07-09/intro-to-git.pdf)).

Follow this thread : **[Pushing changes on Gitorius from QtCreator](http://www.mail-archive.com/maemo-developers@maemo.org/msg26303.html)**.

If you feel comfortable with French, this page related to the translation of Qt Creator entitled **[Traduction de Qt Creator](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/wiki/doku.php?id=qtcreator#informations_utiles)** is also relevant. Give it a try anyway.